# Where is the event listener for submission the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events, submission

A twitter-like website in Chinese. When I type a message and click a submit "button", a new entry is created. But I can't figure out the event listener for the submit "button".

I studied the source code, there is no form at all, and the "button" is actually an `<a href="javascript:;" class="sendinfo-btn submit-trigger" title="按Ctrl+Enter键发微博">发布</a>` element.

So I think the website is using ajax to do the actual submission. I use google chrome to inspect the submit "button",  but there is no event listener at all! So how could the submission be done?

Here is some relevant html code:

```
<div class="publishBox-ft clearfix">
    <div class="fl">
        <div class="uploadPic">
            <em class="icon-uploadPic"></em>
            <a class="link-lb js-link">图片</a>
        </div>
        <div class="insertFace">
            <em class="icon-face"></em>
            <a class="link-lb js-link">表情</a>
        </div>
        <div class="topic-trigger">
            <em class="icon-topic"></em>
            <a class="link-lb js-link">话题</a>
        </div>
        <div class="insertVideo video-trigger">
            <em class="icon-video"></em>
            <a class="link-lb js-link">视频</a>
        </div>
        <div class="insertPoi">
            <em class="icon-lbsB"></em>
            <span class="sendinfo-lbsbox link-lb">
                <span class="sendinfo-showPoi">
                    <a class="sendinfo-currentPoi sendinfo-changePoi js-link poi-trigger" data-poi-id="null" data-poiname="发布地点">地点</a>
                    <a title="删除位置信息" class="js-link sendinfo-closePoi default-close-icon"></a>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fr">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="sendinfo-btn submit-trigger" title="按Ctrl+Enter键发微博">发布</a>
        <span class="js-wordCounter word-counter sendinfoTip">还可以输<span class="char-constantia">152</span>字</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If somebody want to go the acutal website to study, here is the url and username and password:
http://t.163.com/4729009840
username: fatieji_test@163.com
password: 1a2b3c4d

Be aware: the website is in Chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is bound at runtime in the [JavaScript file](http://static.t.126.net/frontend/js/app/app1.1.2.js).

The relevant parts to search for are `t.sendBtnElem=$(t.wrapperElem.$(".sendinfo-btn")[0])` and `t.sendBtnElem.addEvent("click", ...`

Comment: How did you figure it out? And would you please tell me how to trigger the submission by javascript? I injected jquery and tried `$('a:contains("发布")').click()` which didn't do the submission.

Comment: Loaded page, viewed the source, searched for `.js"` to cycle through the JavaScript files, guessed which one was the main JavaScript file, loaded that in a tab, did a search for `sendinfo-btn` (in your question), saw the developer had assigned it to `t.sendBtnElem`, then searched for `sendBtnElem` :-)

Comment: Hi @andyb, I tried your method, but I can only find this file: http://static.t.126.net/frontend/microblog/256455/script/page/home.js

Comment: When I do a _View page source_ in Chrome, line 1046 of the [link](http://t.163.com/session) in your original question is `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.t.126.net/frontend/js/app/app1.1.2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: @andyb. But you didn't login(you could see the username and password in my post). I couldn't find that file any more after login. So the problem is still unresolved. Anyway, thank you very much for the kind help.

Comment: @Peter Long yes I did not log in, sorry. I did log in and have another look at the logged in page source. I did find `bindEvent:function(){this.textarea=new i(this.$elem.find("textarea")),this.$elem.delegate(".submit-trigger","click",d.proxy(this.onSubmit,this))` which shows jQuery [proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) being used. However the code is fairly well obfuscated. It is certainly possible to trace the variables but it would be time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

This is done using Javascript code that adds a `click` handler at runtime.